# atomic deployments with Nginx and PHP FPM

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, php5, deployment

I'm trying to get atomic deployments, I don't want to lose/drop any requests.

I deploy the code using Capistrano, classic situation were you have a 'current' dir that is a symlink to
the latest release in the 'release' folder.
I'm using Nginx, PHP 5.5 FPM with Opcache.
Following the idea of just using $realpath_root in Nginx I'm expecting that a simple nginx reload would suffice, but it's not.
With nginx reload it seems that I'm not losing any requests but php-fpm is still executing the code from the previous old dir. 
If I do a 'php-fpm reload' then php fpm is reading from the new dir but I can still see that I'm losing some requests:

> 'recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream'

The question is: **should I reload PHP FPM or not?**

From what I understand  nginx is passing the path to php-fpm and from the nginx debug log I can see that the path passed is the right one but php-fpm still executes the old one.

```
2014/09/23 17:13:22 [debug] 26234#0: *1742 http script var: "/shop/www/htdocs/current/web"
2014/09/23 17:13:22 [debug] 26234#0: *1742 posix_memalign: 00000000010517A0:4096 @16
2014/09/23 17:13:22 [debug] 26234#0: *1742 http script copy: "SCRIPT_FILENAME"
2014/09/23 17:13:22 [debug] 26234#0: *1742 http script var: "/shop/www/htdocs/ive/releases/20140923124417/web"
2014/09/23 17:13:22 [debug] 26234#0: *1742 http script var: "/app.php"
2014/09/23 17:13:22 [debug] 26234#0: *1742 fastcgi param: "SCRIPT_FILENAME: /shop/www/htdocs/live/releases/20140923124417/web/app.php"
2014/09/23 17:13:22 [debug] 26234#0: *1742 http script copy: "DOCUMENT_ROOT"
2014/09/23 17:13:22 [debug] 26234#0: *1742 http script var: "/shop/www/htdocs/live/releases/20140923124417/web"
2014/09/23 17:13:22 [debug] 26234#0: *1742 fastcgi param: "DOCUMENT_ROOT: /shop/www/htdocs/live/releases/20140923124417/web"
2014/09/23 17:13:22 [debug] 26234#0: *1742 http script copy: "APPLICATION_ENV"
```

What am I missing? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have made changes to the default OPcache configuration.

The defaults are:

```
opcache.validate_timestamps = 1
opcache.revalidate_freq = 2
```

This specifies whether and for how long OPcache should wait before checking to see if a file on disk has changed. In this case, yes, and after two seconds.

First, try re-enabling this option, as it sounds like you have turned it off.

Comment: why? opcache works with realpath as far as I know.

Comment: checking what opcache contains I can see different paths for the same file, so it shouldn't be the problem... right?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced that issue then finally I make a solution.

```
$ curl -sO http://gordalina.github.io/cachetool/downloads/cachetool.phar
$ chmod +x cachetool.phar
```

You can connect to a automatically guessed fastcgi server (if /var/run/php5-fpm.sock is a file or 127.0.0.1:9000)

```
apc
  apc:bin:dump             Get a binary dump of files and user variables
  apc:bin:load             Load a binary dump into the APC file and user variables
  apc:cache:clear          Clears APC cache (user, system or all)
  apc:cache:info           Shows APC user & system cache information
  apc:cache:info:file      Shows APC file cache information
  apc:key:delete           Deletes an APC key
  apc:key:exists           Checks if an APC key exists
  apc:key:fetch            Shows the content of an APC key
  apc:key:store            Store an APC key with given value
  apc:sma:info             Show APC shared memory allocation information
opcache
  opcache:configuration    Get configuration information about the cache
  opcache:reset            Resets the contents of the opcode cache
  opcache:status           Show summary information about the opcode cache
  opcache:status:scripts   Show scripts in the opcode cache
```

Example :

```
    [root@ip-172-31-5-244 ~]# php cachetool.phar opcache:status
+----------------------+---------------------------------+
| Name                 | Value                           |
+----------------------+---------------------------------+
| Enabled              | Yes                             |
| Cache full           | No                              |
| Restart pending      | No                              |
| Restart in progress  | No                              |
| Memory used          | 42.71 MiB                       |
| Memory free          | 85.29 MiB                       |
| Memory wasted (%)    | 0 b (0%)                        |
| Strings buffer size  | 8 MiB                           |
| Strings memory used  | 5.31 MiB                        |
| Strings memory free  | 2.69 MiB                        |
| Number of strings    | 103847                          |
+----------------------+---------------------------------+
| Cached scripts       | 1261                            |
| Cached keys          | 2748                            |
| Max cached keys      | 7963                            |
| Start time           | Thu, 08 Feb 2018 02:28:56 +0000 |
| Last restart time    | Thu, 08 Feb 2018 03:10:19 +0000 |
| Oom restarts         | 0                               |
| Hash restarts        | 0                               |
| Manual restarts      | 1                               |
| Hits                 | 47839                           |
| Misses               | 1269                            |
| Blacklist misses (%) | 0 (0%)                          |
| Opcache hit rate     | 97.415899649752                 |
+----------------------+---------------------------------+
[root@ip-172-31-5-244 ~]#
[root@ip-172-31-5-244 ~]#
[root@ip-172-31-5-244 ~]# php cachetool.phar opcache:reset
[root@ip-172-31-5-244 ~]#
[root@ip-172-31-5-244 ~]#
[root@ip-172-31-5-244 ~]# php cachetool.phar opcache:status
+----------------------+---------------------------------+
| Name                 | Value                           |
+----------------------+---------------------------------+
| Enabled              | Yes                             |
| Cache full           | No                              |
| Restart pending      | No                              |
| Restart in progress  | No                              |
| Memory used          | 10.43 MiB                       |
| Memory free          | 117.57 MiB                      |
| Memory wasted (%)    | 0 b (0%)                        |
| Strings buffer size  | 8 MiB                           |
| Strings memory used  | 545.69 KiB                      |
| Strings memory free  | 7.47 MiB                        |
| Number of strings    | 103847                          |
+----------------------+---------------------------------+
| Cached scripts       | 0                               |
| Cached keys          | 0                               |
| Max cached keys      | 7963                            |
| Start time           | Thu, 08 Feb 2018 02:28:56 +0000 |
| Last restart time    | Thu, 08 Feb 2018 03:19:00 +0000 |
| Oom restarts         | 0                               |
| Hash restarts        | 0                               |
| Manual restarts      | 2                               |
| Hits                 | 0                               |
| Misses               | 2                               |
| Blacklist misses (%) | 0 (0%)                          |
| Opcache hit rate     | 0                               |
+----------------------+---------------------------------+
```

You can notice that the memory , cache keys , hits everythings became 0 :-). Its very useful. I also intrigrated it with Ansible easily.

Its application for apcu and others stuffs : Check more there 
http://gordalina.github.io/cachetool/